# Interesting Computing stuff in designing User Interfaces

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, ajax, user-interface

I am working on a Search Application and using open source Search Engine Lucene. Lucene is returning results in few milliseconds. My question is related to the link given below. It would be great if you can visit this link:

http://www.netrics.com/demo/

Click on names and then type any name and it will start rendering and change the results based on each character keyed in. I know it is something like Google Instant. I have read some answers on SO on Google Instant feature but they were bit complex for me as I am not from the UI world.

I just want to know the technology or a simple Algorithm that can make me do this stuff with a bit of details. I dont have much idea on UI stuff. As I mentioned that my search infrastructure is returning results in super quick way, so now its an interesting "UI" Computing problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have really fast search engine - it's quite easy to do, but requires lot of resources server-side.

Firstly, use tool like Firebug (in firefox) or Dragonfly (Opera) or similar to preview what happening when you change any char in search query.

Site is requesting urls like that:
https://demos.netrics.com/ncc7/find_json?table_name=names1M&sensitivity=0.843&query=abc&callback=jsonp1330501624190&_=1330501901072
and server-side scripts returns JSON object, which is decoded and search results are updated client-side (using js).

Its not very complicated and difficult to do, but as I said - it'll require lot's of server resources when your app get popular.

Comment: I can see the query parameter in the URL, thats perfect. But I still did not understand the callback parameter. JSON's should all be related to server side, and the client should just give server the query and server may return the JSON. What it has to do with the client requesting some json's in the query? Also can it be XML instead of JSON? Why particularly JSON?