# Understanding callback part in a URL

Tags: javascript, json, http

I am very new to UI/HTTP stuff.

Say I have a URL:

https://demos.netrics.com/ncc7/find_json?table_name=names1M&sensitivity=0.843&query=abc&callback=jsonp1330501624190&_=1330501901072

I just want to decode it in plain english for the part callback=jsonp1330501624190&_=1330501901072.

What does it mean? Actually my query is sent to the server (there is the query parameter in the URL) and I get back JSON from the server. This is fine. But what does it mean to have json stuff (as I have mentioned above) in URL from the client end?

Here is my original question which led me to the above question:
[Interesting Computing stuff in designing User Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495294/interesting-computing-stuff-in-designing-user-interfaces)

Comment: First off: JSONP. Read up on JSONP, even Wikipedia will do. Then look at the response sent back after you visit the URL you're asking about and it should be clear to you what that `callback=` parameter could be up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client side there should be a function like this, which will process the response object.

```
function jsonp1330501624190(result){

  // process result

}
```

These links might be useful :

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/07/16/what-is-jsonp.html

http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/